# phonegap app crashes on android first time entering data into sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova

We have a problem with reading data into a sqlite database, in a android phonegap app, with html5sql.js. We are getting the data (a webservice that returns a bunch of insert statements +/- 4mb) from the server with an ajax call, and then inserts the data into the db. On IOS and desktop browsers it works fine, but on android the sqlite db crashes the first time you've start up the app. If we kill the app in the multitask menu, and start it again everything works fine...

The error we get is the following:

*10-21 11:54:02.165: E/SQLiteLog(12184): (13) statement aborts at 24: [INSERT INTO Products (ProductID, MaterialNr, LangCodeSAP, LangCodeISO, MaterialName, ProductText, Price, StaggeredPrices, ModifiedDate) VALUES ('112933', '1004612-9866', 'N', 'NL', 'O-*

Anybody?

Greetings
Sjors

Comment: how ur create table command looks like?

Comment: Like this:CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Products (ProductID INTEGER Unique, MaterialNr, LangCodeSAP, LangCodeISO, MaterialName, ProductText TEXT, Price, StaggeredPrices, ModifiedDate, Image)

Comment: have u uninstalled and tried?

Comment: Yes multiple times, tried on different devices / emulators

Comment: Problem may be somewhere in index. start your index from '0' when inserting and selecting..

Comment: sorry, that's not the problem...

Comment: Is there a chance that the insert statement is occurring before the database has a chance to be created and opened? The fact that when you kill the app and restart makes it work makes me think that the insert statement is happening and failing, and then the database is being created. Then the next time you start the app, the database is there and the insert happens just fine.

Comment: That's not the case. Because we're already using the database before executing the insert statements.

Comment: Same problem here too